# Как создать редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса.

Tags: c++

Хочу создать редактор кода на С++ с подсветкой кода, но не знаю, как сделать подсветку.
Я видел, что можно создать подсветку синтаксиса на html и css, но как перенести все это, например, в windows form?

Comment: Оффтоп: Простите, но зачем?

Comment: @IsM ну может в целях самообучения например

Comment: Для целей самообучения могу посоветовать посмотреть исходный код Notepad++ к примеру. Если важна только идея, можно воспользоваться умными мыслями например в компоненте [FastColoredTextBox][1]


  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Comment: @huxi: А с синтаксическим анализом кода на C++ вы уже справились, и проблема только в визуализации подсветки? Так вы ж монстр!

Comment: @VladD, в редакторах насколько я помню подобное сводилось к сопоставлению ключевых слов языка определенным цветам. Или нет?

Comment: @Alexey123: вот смотрите. Код

    A B(C);

— это объявление переменной и инициализация (типа `int x(y)`), или forward-декларация функции (`void f(int)`)? Подсвечивать `B` цветом для функций, или для переменных? Допустим, что `A`, `B`, и `C` — пользовательские типы или переменные.

Comment: >в редакторах насколько я помню подобное сводилось к сопоставлению ключевых слов языка определенным цветам

это слишком простой случай. Скажем, в языке могут быть контекстно-зависимые ключевые слова, которые в одной ситуации являются  ключевыми, а в другой - обычными литералами. Например,  **add**, **remove**, **select**, **where** из C# или  **override** и **final**  в С++11. В одних случаях эти слова должны быть подсвечены, а в других - нет

Comment: @VladD, ну это уже дальнейшее развитие, которое можно разделить и свести к добавлению лексемы в тот или иной словарь. А вот с контекстно-зависимыми да, может быть беда.

Просто вспомнился сразу Scintilla, конкретно SciTE с его настройкой ключевых слов и их цветов под свои нужды.

Comment: Ну что вы все застращали человека?

--

Пусть сделает попроще. Подсветит ключевые слова С++, комментарии и строки.

Все равно для этого какой-то парсер ему придется написать.

Comment: @avp: Насчёт сложности парсинга C++ ещё немного [тут](/questions/239051#239115).

Comment: Согласен с @avp, еще идентификаторы, числовые константы и директивы препроцессора можно добавить. Для всего этого полноценный парсинг не нужен, достаточно только сканера, а это регулярка или конечный автомат всего лишь.

Comment: @VladD, да, но emacs с раскраской кода успешно справился.

Comment: @avp: так это ж emacs! Столлман и gcc написал, ему-то написать парсер C++ плёвое дело.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться компонентом RichTextBox из Windows Forms и его методами по работе с поиском и выделенным текстом. К сожалению могу привести пример только на C# для одного первого слова, но думаю в С++ перевести, организовать цикл поиска и прочее не составит трудностей.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int start, curent;

    curent = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    start = richTextBox1.Find("привет");

    if (start != -1)
    {
        //выделяем текст цветом
        richTextBox1.Select(start, 6);
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0x78FF0000);

        //возвращаем каретку на место
        richTextBox1.Select(curent, 0);
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0x00000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Соглашусь, выбор правильного компонента для хранения и отображения текста - уже пол-дела. Но большая часть решений все равно велосипеды. Например, такое: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2006/12/14/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting/ А лучше взять готовое решение. Например, http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Это может пригодиться - [TextEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor)